# Switch to a specific viewcontroller from any viewcontroller using - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I would like to jump to a specific screen (view) after the user has backgrounded the app.

I can jump to another screen if I specify which screen I am leaving from, but I want to move from any screen.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, depending on the structure of your app.

For example, if your app's content is a single navigation controller, you can simply push the desired view onto the navigation controller. Or you could pop to the root view and then push the desired view.

If a tab controller, you can push the view on a specific tab and then manually set the tab controller's selected tab.

Or if the view is modal, you could present it on any of the above, or even on the window of the app itself.

Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I am using modal. Can you give me an example with some code?

Answer (score 0):

In app delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *mainNavController;
```

In did finish launching:

```
self.mainNavController = // do your initialization here

self.window.rootViewController = self.mainNavController;
```

In did become active:

```
[self.mainNavController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
```

Or you even can change the root view controller:

```
self.window.rootViewController = newViewController;
```

You can access your main navigation from any place in your code by calling;

```
UINavigationController *mainNav = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] mainNavController];
```

And do any your stuff with it.